# convert coordinates from one resolution to another

Tags: java, image, math, processing

I have an image at a resolution of `512x512` pixels and I need to map a point in this image, selected through a mouse's click, to a point in the same image but at a resolution of `1024x1024`.

I think that the problem is easy but I'm missing something. I tried calculating the mapping with a classical mathematical proportion like:

```
xp = x*1024/512
```

But it obviously doubles the value of `x` without actually making a map/conversion.
How should I make this mapping?

**EDIT**
As suggested in the comments, the core of the question is:
How can I make a projection of a point in a `512x512` image to a `1024x1024` image?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do. If the 512x512 was upscaled to 1024x1024 then a pixel (x,y) in the smaller image would map to the pixel (2*x,2*y) in the larger image, so you would do x' = x * (1024/512) which is x' = 2x. You'd do the same for the y coordinate.

Comment: @tgdavies Actually I would like that if I a click at some point in the `512x512` and get the coordinate i.e. `(30,30)` then this should have a similar value in the `1024x1024` if I'm near the top-left corner. Like if I have a geographical map, where proportions aren't fully respected. Am I missing something and double the value is correct?

Comment: In your question you say *y* = x*1024/512 -- you don't want to mix the x and y coordinates. I'm not sure what you mean by "a geographical map, where proportions aren't fully respected". If you want map from one projection to another that's more complicated.

Comment: Yes, doubling the value is correct, assuming the transformation is linear.

Comment: Well yes, I didn't use y as the "vertical axis" in the question, it was just to call the result of that calculation. By the way yes, probably it's a projection-related problem.

Comment: You'll need to edit your question and explain what projections you are trying to convert between.

Comment: Doubling the value of x (and y) *is* a mapping.

Comment: You should add the actual code you are using, and explain why you think you are "missing something" -- what is happening which is undesired/unexpected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your math checks out: if one image is 512x512 and the other is 1024x1024 the scale factor is 2 (multiplying x, y coordinates by 2 should do the trick.

Alternatively you can use [`map()`](https://processing.org/reference/map_.html), but in this trivial case it might be more simpler to just use the scale factor directly if you also need to maintain the mapped x,y values as integers.

Here's a basic sketch to demonstrate your mapping (and if you hold the mouse pressed it will use `map()` instead, though the results are the same and you'll notice no difference):

```java
PImage img512, img1024;

void setup(){
  size(1536, 1024);
  strokeWeight(2);
  
  img512  = makeTestImage(512, 512);
  img1024 = makeTestImage(1024, 1024);
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  image(img512, 0, 0);
  image(img1024, 512, 0);
  
  int x = mouseX;
  int y = mouseY;
  
  if((x >= 0 && x < 512) &&
     (y >= 0 && y < 512)){
     
       
      // for debugging pruposes compare with map() when mousePressed
      int xp, yp;
      if(mousePressed){
        xp = (int)map(x, 0, 512, 0, 1024);
        yp = (int)map(y, 0, 512, 0, 1024);
      }else{
        xp = x * 1024 / 512;
        yp = y * 1024 / 512;    
      }
      
      drawCrosshair(x, y, color(0), String.format("original [%d,%d]", x, y));
      // for visualisation purposes offset x ( since we're drawing the 1024 image at 512, 0 )
      drawCrosshair(xp + 512, yp, color(255), String.format("mapped [%d,%d]", xp, yp));
  }
  
}

void drawCrosshair(float x, float y, color c, String label){
  stroke(c);
  // h
  line(0, y, width, y);
  // v
  line(x, 0, x, height);
  text(label, x - 100, y);
}

PImage makeTestImage(int w, int h){
  pushStyle();
  colorMode(HSB, 255, 255, 255);
  
  PImage out = createImage(w, h, RGB);
  
  out.loadPixels();
  
  for(int i = 0 ; i < out.pixels.length; i++){
    out.pixels[i] = color(i % 255, 128, 128);
  }
  
  out.updatePixels();
  
  popStyle();
  
  return out;
}
```

Note that the mapped coordinate is displayed coorectly, but it's rendered with an offset of 512 pixels given the second `PImage` is rendered to the right of the first.

Here's a modified version that accesses `pixels[]` to copy a single pixel from one image to another:

```
PImage img512, img1024;

void setup(){
  size(1536, 1024);
  strokeWeight(2);
  
  img512  = makeTestImage(512, 512);
  img1024 = makeTestImage(1024, 1024);
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  image(img512, 0, 0);
  image(img1024, 512, 0);
  
  int x = mouseX;
  int y = mouseY;
  
  if((x >= 0 && x < 512) &&
     (y >= 0 && y < 512)){
     
       
      // for debugging pruposes compare with map() when mousePressed
      int xp, yp;
      if(mousePressed){
        xp = (int)map(x, 0, 512, 0, 1024);
        yp = (int)map(y, 0, 512, 0, 1024);
        
        // test 1D pixel index
        copyPixel(img512, img1024, x, y);
        
      }else{
        xp = x * 1024 / 512;
        yp = y * 1024 / 512;    
      }
      
      drawCrosshair(x, y, color(0), String.format("original [%d,%d]", x, y));
      // for visualisation purposes offset x ( since we're drawing the 1024 image at 512, 0 )
      drawCrosshair(xp + 512, yp, color(255), String.format("mapped [%d,%d]", xp, yp));
  }
  
}

void copyPixel(PImage from, PImage to, int xsrc, int ysrc){
  xsrc = constrain(xsrc, 0, from.width);
  ysrc = constrain(ysrc, 0, from.height);
  
  from.loadPixels();
  to.loadPixels();
  
  int fromIndex = xsrc + (ysrc * from.width);
  
  float scaleFactor = (float)to.width / from.width;
  int xdst = (int)(xsrc * scaleFactor);
  int ydst = (int)(ysrc * scaleFactor);
  
  int toIndex = xdst + (ydst * to.width);
  
  to.pixels[toIndex] = from.pixels[fromIndex];
  
  to.updatePixels();
}


void drawCrosshair(float x, float y, color c, String label){
  stroke(c);
  // h
  line(0, y, width, y);
  // v
  line(x, 0, x, height);
  text(label, x - 100, y);
}

PImage makeTestImage(int w, int h){
  pushStyle();
  colorMode(HSB, 255, 255, 255);
  
  PImage out = createImage(w, h, RGB);
  
  out.loadPixels();
  
  for(int i = 0 ; i < out.pixels.length; i++){
    out.pixels[i] = color(i % 255, 128, 128);
  }
  
  out.updatePixels();
  
  popStyle();
  
  return out;
}
```

As you drag you'll notice colours around the white crosshair change.
The above is more to demonstrate mapping from 2D x,y indices to an 1D `pixels[]` index.
(If you simply want to swap a single pixel using PImage's `get()` and `set()` functions would be simpler. You can also achieve a similar effect with `PImage`'s [`copy()`](https://processing.org/reference/copy_.html) (specifying source and destination width and height of 1 pixel))

Alternatively you can call [`resize()`](https://processing.org/reference/PImage_resize_.html) on one image to match the dimensions of the other and have 1:1 mapping between pixels.